# How to use U2.Data.Client for .NET Core Web API?

Tags: uniobjects, u2netdk

I am looking to create a connection with Universe DB using .NET Core Web API and run SELECT queries but I am getting an error and have heard that U2.Data.Client cannot be used for .NET Core. Is there any workaround for this?

Below is the code which I am trying to execute but an exception is thrown while initializing U2Connection:

```cs
U2Connection con = new U2Connection();
U2ConnectionStringBuilder csb = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.AccessMode = "Native";
csb.RpcServiceType = "uvcs";
csb.Database = "HS.SALES";
csb.UserID = "user";
csb.Password = "password";
csb.Server = "localhost";
csb.ServerType = "universe";
con.ConnectionString = csb.ToString();
con.Open();
```

These are the exceptions which I get when calling the U2Connection constructor:
**System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'U2.Data.Client.U2Connection' threw an exception.'**

**MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Security.Policy.Evidence System.Reflection.Assembly.get_Evidence()'.**

Comment: Please add the exception to the question when you get the chance

Comment: @webthaumaturge added the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no .Net core version of Universe database connector yet! If you are using .Net core 2.x you can target .Net Framework as workaround to be able to use a .Net Framework library where you manage you Universe database access by using the available connector from U2 Toolkit for .NET.
Hope this will help you.